# Why does cuCtxCreate return old context?

Tags: cuda, cuda-context

i have installed:
CUDA sdk 4.2 64,
CUDA toolkit 4.2 64,
CUDA devdriver 4.2 64,

I checked every nvcuda.dll in \windows - all of them, are 4.2 version, but when i create a context with driver api and check it verison with cuCtxGetApiVersion - it shows me "3010"

I do not really care about that version, but when i try to use runtime api with that context(need to mix them) - it shows me error 49(cudaErrorIncompatibleDriverContext)

any ideas, what is going on and how to make it work together?

seems it is not some issue with windows - running the same project under linux results in the same 3010 API version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem - i was exporting "cuCtxCreate" function directly during execution(it is other language - no cuda.h). After looking in original cuda.h i found that it defines other name for that functrion, basing on some sort of smartass defines.
And that new function "cuCtxCreate_v2" creates a good context.

/facepalm